# inserting image in database through sqlite in android application

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview

I am creating an android application in which I have to insert an image into a local database. Then fetch that image and show in a listview. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Thanks
Tushar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why would you put an image in a database? Just store the image on the SDCard and hold onto its location in the database. Then when you're ready display it in your listview.

What have you tried so far? When you say "guide me", what level of guidance do you need? Have you installed Android? Do you know Java? etc etc. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @dredel i have inserted the image in local database that is sd card.I need basaic level of sqlite database part.I am learning android thats why i want to put image in database

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting Images from the internet then just store the Url of the Image in the DataBase and when you want to use it just convert it to bitmap .

Another way is to save your images`s Path into the Database.

Both way you can store the reference path of your image resource ...

Comment: http://photos.worldisround.com/photos/28/295/292.jpg .....You can take this url as an example you can convert this string into a bit map and then you can set at BitmapResource to imageView object...

Comment: ,,images i have,,but do you have any sample code avalable for sqlite database integration ??

Comment: Are you Confortable with how to create database and insert query if you are not then go to this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html you can refer this......Or You can store your images into asset folder and from here you can give the path till your asset folder by making unique name as(image1) so that you can take the path in string like ("image"+i) by doing this you can get (path+imagename) to get your image`s path